# How much voltage I need to light up this led

Tags: led

I have a RL80-UR543 LED 8MM. How much voltage I need if I use a resistor of 100Ohm?

Answer (score 1):

Forward Current (If) = 20 mA   and

Forward Voltage (Vf) = 1.7V to 2.8V
is written on datasheet

- maximum voltage  = 20mA*100ohm + 2.8V = 4.8V

Comment: I conntect it to a battery without any resistor and nothing happened. Bettery is 1.5v

Comment: I calculated theoretical maximum voltage according to your requirements. Using leds without current control not a good way.